# How to override TestMethod of MSTest

Tags: mstest

I have a situation where I have created a test framework on MSTEST.

Actually, we have integrated POM(Page object Model) using MSTEST

My TestSuite classes is using TestMethod annotation and those testsuites execute all testcase function define in another class.

I am generating trx report using below command line:-

```
MSTest.exe /testcontainer:"D:\AutomationScript\bin\Debug\AutomationScript.dll" /resultsfile:D:\Testcases_Reports\TestResultFinalTest.trx
```

In trx report all TestMethods which basically are my suites are coming while I need to append my testcases function name as well which are define in another class and called by my suites functions having TestMethod annotation

So How can I override TestMethod.

Any solution will be appreciated

Comment: I do really understand your Question. Do want to Override the Attribute `TestMethod` or do you want to override a method you want to test?

Comment: My final goal is to add my function name present in my other class besides funcion name of suites which having arribute TestMethod right now .. I believe by adding some logic in Testmenthod attribute I can achive my goal .. so I want to Override the Attribute TestMethod

Comment: Unfortunately TestMethodAttribute is sealed. `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
  public sealed class TestMethodAttribute : Attribute`

Comment: oh .. No Issue ... Thanks to let me know

Comment: Do you have any idea how to achieve same in my current situation? any suggestion will be helpful and appreciated

Comment: Well i dont know if this helps but you could switch your Test-Framework to, for example, NUnit.

Comment: ok @lokusking .. thanks for the response :)